# Is writing a research paper necessary for thesis?

Tags: publications, thesis

I'm from Computer Science field and usually I've seen students are required to publish a few research papers to be eligible for writing a thesis. I'm talking about masters level thesis here.

As far as I know the rationale behind this is that research papers are usually well evaluated by the conference committee but what if someone's  research doesn't get published?

I'm assuming their research to be good enough but is rejected by conference people because they had better alternatives.

Are they eligible to write the thesis? They don't usually allow it in my college. Is it the case everywhere?

If the answer goes along the line that it must be acceptable in a lower rated conference then why go for external evaluations anyway since I've heard they have poor evaluations.

Comment: _*usually* I've seen students are *required* to publish a few research papers to be *eligible for writing* a thesis_ Can you clarify what you mean? With particular reference to emphasised words. _As far as I know the rationale behind this is that research papers are usually well evaluated by the conference committee_ Can you explain relevance? A thesis should be independently evaluated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are [students required to publish to be] eligible to write the thesis?

No, this is institution dependent.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing varies widely from place to place. In the US it would be fairly unusual at the MS level. But, what ever it is, the rules of your university are what they are and you need to follow them to be successful there. If they permit lower quality publications, then they do. It isn't a good idea to just try for the lowest acceptable quality, but if you are rejected at a high level and a lower level will work, then do that.

You are still very early in your career. Your earliest work isn't likely to be your best work and things can improve as you learn more and get more experience.

Ultimately, the why doesn't matter a lot. You follow the rules as you find them. But I expect that it involves finding a way for you to get early experience.